# Encountering challenges in configuring OIDC-based authentication for Amazon EKS using Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, amazon-eks

I've successfully set up an EKS cluster in my AWS account and configured OIDC authentication with Azure AD as the identity provider, following the instructions in this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-azure-active-directory-to-authenticate-to-amazon-eks/).

However, when attempting to execute the command `kubectl --user=azure-user get nodes`, I encountered the following error:

```
E1220 17:01:05.101980   22361 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "<my-cluster-api-endpoint-redacted>/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin failed with exit code 1
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin failed with exit code 1
```

Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?

Note: I've slightly modified my error message to conceal my cluster endpoint, replacing it with `<my-cluster-api-endpoint-redacted>`.

Thanks!